# Convert String to HashSet in Java

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion, hashset

I am interested in converting a string to a `HashSet` of charcters, But `HashSet` takes in a collection in the constructor. I tried

`HashSet<Character> result = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()));`

(where `word` is the String) and it doesn't seem to work (maybe failed to box `char` into `Character` ?)

How should I do such conversion?

Comment: Re: "maybe failed to box `char` into `Character`": It's not a matter of autoboxing `char` into `Character`, but rather, of autoboxing  `char[]` into `Character[]` -- which isn't supported. (Autoboxing `char` into `Character` isn't just a compile-time cast, it also involves actually creating or retrieving the `Character` instance at runtime. So autoboxing `char[]` into `Character[]` would involve automatically looping over the array, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution using Java8 streams:

```
HashSet<Character> charsSet = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "teststring";
    HashSet<Character> charsSet = str.chars()
            .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    System.out.println(charsSet);
}
```

Will output:

```
[r, s, t, e, g, i, n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
      String word="holdup";
      char[] ch = word.toCharArray();
      HashSet<Character> result = new HashSet<Character>();
      
      for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
      {
        result.add(ch[i]);
      }
       System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
 [p, d, u, h, l, o]
```